# Why would people use `$a = $b = 2;` in PHP?

Tags: php

Why would people use this format? Whats different between this and `$a=2; $b=2;`?

Comment: Just a shortcut. The result of an assignment in PHP is the value that was assigned, which allows you to chain assignments together to set multiple variables to the same value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not having to retype the `2`. This is useful if the `2` changes to a `3` at some point.

Comment: Ok, so if I was to redifine $b at a later stage, it wouldn't effect $a?

Comment: @rickyduck: No, since assignment is done by value.  That is, in the above example ($a = $b = 2), $b is assigned the value of 2, and then $a is assigned the value of $b (the assignment operator has right-associativity, meaning it works 'from the right').  If you were to call $a =& $b = 2, THEN, changes you made to $b would affect $a.

Comment: @Pete171: Useful information, but surely you mean "Yes, it wouldn't affect $a" in this context. (?)

Comment: @Pete171: I've tried `$a =& $b = 2;` and I get a parse error.  I can do `$b = 2; $a =& $b;` though.  I haven't been able to find any instances where chaining and assignment by reference can be used together.

Answer (score 7):

Functionally? nothing. They both do the same thing "set variables $a and $b to 2". But, it does communicate something to your fellow programmers and it is faster/easier in some circumstances. For example

```
for($i = $j = 0; $i < 5; $i++, $j--) echo "$i $j \n";
```

Outputs:

```
0 0
1 -1
2 -2
3 -3
4 -4
```

Of course, if you need $i and $j to initialize to something more useful, say, `floor( count( $myArr ) / 2 )`, it can also be useful that way.

Then there are other, similar uses:

```
$j = ( $i = 1 ) - 1; // $i = 1, $j = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. They are exactly the same, it's just a matter of personal preference or coding style. Also, if you redefine `$b`, `$a` will not change, which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Its simply the shorter way to set both variables to 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shorter coding style and is particularly useful when the various elements (the `$a`, `$b` and `2` in your example) are significantly longer.  Especially when the RHS is long.

For example:

```
$currentElement = $firstElement = $this->someCalculation($someparameter, $someotherparamter)->root;
```